# K&R exercise 1-8 improvement

Tags: c

So the program works, but it works like so:

```
input: 3 blanks
output:
newlines:0
tabs:0
blanks:1
newlines:0
tabs:0
blanks:2
newlines:0
tabs:0
blanks:3
newlines:1
tabs:0
blanks:3
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int c, nl, t, b;
    nl = 0;
    t = 0;
    b = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == '\t')
            ++t;
        if (c == ' ')
            ++b;
        printf("newlines:%d\ntabs:%d\nblanks%d\n", nl, t, b);
    }
}
```

My question is - is it possible to display just the last result, where `blanks:3` is, to omit repetition

```
(newlines:1
tabs:0
blanks:3)?
```

Comment: Move the `printf` outside the loop

Comment: Outside the main loop? Doesn't compile..

Comment: `main()` is a function, not a loop. `while` is the loop. Also, I'd suggest using the standard `int main(void)` signature for the `main` function.

Comment: moved it outside the while loop, there is now no output whatsoever. Can you post code to show exactly what you mean? And why (int main(void))?

Comment: I assume you didn't send an `EOF` condition. Try `CTRL + Z` followed by enter if you're on Windows or `CTRL + D` if you're on linux to send the `EOF` condition so that the loop ends. `int main(void)` is one of the correct signatures for the `main` function as per the latest C standard. The book you're reading is old which is why it uses just `main()`

Comment: Oooh, I see, thank you! But isn't it possible to just edit the code(you said put the printf outside the loop, but that didn't work for me), so I don't have to manually call EOF?

Comment: In that case, you can use a `if(c == '\n')` condition before your `printf` in the question so that it gets printed for every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just move the `printf("newlines:%d\ntabs:%d\nblanks%d\n", nl, t, b);` line after the closing `}` of the `while` loop.

Note how the code is more readable when properly formatted.

Note also that `main` must have a defined return type of `int`.

Here is the modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, nl, t, b;
    nl = 0;
    t = 0;
    b = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == '\t')
            ++t;
        if (c == ' ')
            ++b;
    }
    printf("newlines:%d\ntabs:%d\nblanks%d\n", nl, t, b);

    for(;;);  // infinite loop to keep the output visible

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to change `main()` to  `main(void)`?

Comment: @EsmaeelE: both are valid, as well as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and compatible variants.

Comment: Not relate in this case but I read in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/)  `main()` can accept any number of arguments and completely different from `main(void)`. So I conclude that any version of main that not accept argument must be In this form `int main(void)`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah that was already suggested and it still doesn't work without manually pressing ctrl z for EOF - no output is produced. Tried it in both gcc and an online c compiler (copy pasted your code). Is there no way to declare EOF in the actual program?

Comment: Additionally, EOF ends the program, and that is not optimal as well.

Comment: @JohnDoe: The reason you do not see the output could be that you are executing the program from the IDE, not inside a terminal window. Of course you must signal the end of file manually if you type the input at the terminal, you could also redirect input from a file an output to another file if your IDE supports it and you would see the output there. You can add a hack after the `printf` to wait for a few seconds so the output stays visible.

Comment: @chqrlie Don't worry about it. ;) Thanks again for your answer!